# Appending circles in a line chart only if they have associated notes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I created this nice line graph with circles on each data point: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k537Ldyp/7/)

My issue is with the circles and getting them to appear ONLY if there are "notes" attached to the data point.

```
svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("stroke", "#6b38df")
        .attr("d", valueline);

    svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return x(d.date)
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return y(d.close)
        })
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#BA85FF")
        ;

    svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.date) - paddingForText
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.close) + paddingForText
        })
        //.attr("fill", "white")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.notes
        })
        .classed("notepoint", true)
        .style("font-family", "Roboto")
        .style("font-size", "14px")
        ;
```

In the code above I am attaching the "notes" as a label that appears with the circle, but I only want to the circle for that data point to show if there are notes for it. I want to do this because when there are too many circles on the graph it becomes congested and harder to read.

How can I show the circles ONLY if there are notes attached to the data point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your circles selection, filter the data according to the `notes` property:

```
.data(data.filter(function(d){
    return d.notes
}))
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cerj7s16/1/